# Conditional file and directory installation in `.deb` Packages

Tags: scripts, packaging, deb

Is it possible to create a binary `.deb` package with conditional files and directories installation (e.g. installation of an `init` script in `/etc/init.d/` after being confirmed by the user)?

Comment: What is the point? Packages are installed with admin rights. Why another confirmation is needed? And how is it related to Ubuntu?

Comment: @Pilot6 I would like to make some features optional for installation like creating a daemon. Sorry, my question is about Debian packaging and not Ubuntu (Would you suggest me to ask it elsewhere?).

Comment: You can ask that at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: KaBa, I would suggesting installing the init script anyway, but enable/disable it after confirming with the user. @Pilot6 if either the packaging or the installation happens on Ubuntu, it's fine - since the Debian packaging system is also the primary system on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to interactively ask questions during package installation you should use [debconf](https://wiki.debian.org/debconf). To dynamically create and manage configuration files (and files in `/etc/init.d/` are considered configuration files) [ucf](https://wiki.debian.org/ConfigPackages#ucf) can be used.

A tutorial, on how to use debconf, may be found here:
http://www.fifi.org/doc/debconf-doc/tutorial.html

### Minimal example

#### `debconf` template

Put this in the file `debian/templates`. It contains the text that is shown to the user during installation. Just be sure to replace `demo-pkg` with you actually package name!

```
Template: demo-pkg/install-init.d
Type: boolean
Default: false
Description: Would you like to install a service for this package?
 Services are really cool! They allow stuff to be started in the
 background without you having to start them manually!!!
```

#### Package configuration script

This is where you ask the user (interactively) about the things you need to know. This script is special since, when installing more than one package, all of these files of all packages are run before `dpkg` begins the actual installation process. This means that, if more than one package wants to ask the user something, all questions are asked at the beginning of installation for all packages, instead of later on for each package individually.

Just put the following stuff into a file named `debian/config` and mark it as executable (remember to replace `demo-pkg` with the correct package name):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Make sure this script fails if any unexpected errors happen
set -e

# Load debconf library
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

# Should an init job be installed?
db_input high demo-pkg/install-init.d || true
db_go

# You can also act upon the user's answers using `db_get`
#db_get demo-pkg/install-init.d
#[ "${RET}" = "false"] && echo "I don't think that was a wise decision..."
```

#### Maintainer scripts (`postinst`, `prerm` and `postrm`)

Here we do the actual magic and dynamically add and remove the configuration file/init script. For this to work you have to install your init script as regular file along with your package (I assumed `/usr/share/demo-pkg/init-service` in this example).

The `debian/postinst` file (called after all files were extracted by `dpkg`):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Make sure this script fails if any unexpected errors happen
set -e

# Load debconf library
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

if [ "$1" = "configure" ];
then
    # Check if the user decided the enable the service using `db_get`
    db_get demo-pkg/install-init.d
    if [ "${RET}" != "false" ];
    then
        # Install init script using `ucf`
        ucf /usr/share/demo-pkg/init-service /etc/init.d/demo-service

        # Register init script as service
        update-rc.d demo-service defaults

        # Start service
        invoke-rc.d demo-service start
    fi
fi
```

The `debian/prerm` file (called before files are removed by `dpkg` or the package is upgraded to a newer version):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Make sure this script fails if any unexpected errors happen
set -e

# Load debconf library
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

# Check if the user decided the enable the service using `db_get`
db_get demo-pkg/install-init.d
if [ "${RET}" != "false" ];
then
    # Stop the service before upgrade or removal
    invoke-rc.d demo-service stop

    if [ "$1" = "remove" ] || [ "$1" = "deconfigure" ];
    then
        # Unregister service prior to removal
        update-rc.d -f demo-service remove
    fi
fi
```

The `debian/postrm` file (called after all files were removed by `dpkg`):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Make sure this script fails if any unexpected errors happen
set -e

if [ "$1" = "purge" ];
then
    # Remove service file using `ucf` (checking whether `ucf` is still available first)
    if type ucf >/dev/null 2>&1;
    then
        ucf --purge "/etc/init.d/demo-service"
    fi

    # Remove service file by hand (in case the above failed somehow)
    rm -f "/etc/init.d/demo-service"
fi
```

### Final steps

1. Add a `Pre-Depends:` dependency on `debconf` in the file `debian/control`
2. Add a normal `Depends:` dependency on `ucf` in the file `debian/control`
3. Make sure the file `/usr/share/demo-pkg/init-service` (or whatever you call it) gets installed properly

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and mark as accepted answer if this helped you! Please do ask for clarification if something doesn't make sense to you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will use it tomorrow and if there is any question, I will get back to you. Sure, I will mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks! I just added some extra commands that make sure that the service is registered and started correctly.

Comment: @KaBa: Please visit the [Ask Ubuntu Tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) to better understand how this site works, as it is  a Q&A site and *quite different from a forum...*

Comment: @KaBa Did you mark your `debian/config` file as executable (Right-click -> Properties -> Permissions -> Executable OR `chmod +x "${filename}"`) ? Does the `debian/config` file include the shebang line ("`#!/bin/sh`")?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I created a new simple package. Now, I get this error : Can't locate object method "new" via package "Debconf::Element::Noninteractive::[boolean]" (perhaps you forgot to load "Debconf::Element::Noninteractive::[boolean]"?) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd.pm line 68, <GEN1> line 1.

Comment: I fixed the problem with this error by removing brackets around `boolean` in `templates` file. There is no error message but, it still does not ask any question! I build the package using 'dpkg-deb -b' and installing it by 'dpkg -i'.

Comment: Since you are serious about this, I decided to actually test the exact steps I've posted; and indeed it doesn't work! :-) Fortunately the solution to this issue is quite simple: In `debian/config` the question `demo-pkg/install-init.d` is asked with priority `medium` (`db_input high demo-pkg/install-init.d`), however only questions with priority `high` or greater are actually asked during installation. (1/2)

Comment: To fix this you must change the word `medium` to `high` in the `debian/config` file. Additionally since have already installed the package at least once at this point, you must *manually* purge the `debconf` cache for your package, which can be done using the command `echo "PURGE" | sudo debconf-communicate demo-pkg` (where `demo-pkg` is your package name). (2/2)

Comment: Just an extra note: Debian packages are usually created using the `dpkg-buildpackage` command. While creating package for internal use using `dpkg-deb -b` is fine, it's not the "offical way" and you might face trouble later on when trying to hand your (source) packages to other people.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. I couldn't get result with `dpkg-deb -b` so I tried to use `dpkg-buildpackage`. But, it says `dpkg-source: error: syntax error in mydeb/debian/control at line 9: first block lacks a source field`. This is a binary package without any source file. Should `dpkg-buildpackage` be used with special parameters in a special path?

Comment: @alexander255 Thank you so much finally, it worked!

Comment: Glad it works for you now! About the `dpkg-buildpackage` error: Could it be that you assembled all package files "by hand" (using another binary package as reference)? In that case your package directory will not contain any information on how to create source packages. It's probably best to just keep your current build structure for now, but, should you ever require source packages or `dh` (debhelper) support, then just remember that you can easily create a "proper" package using `dh_make -n` and merge your current configuration into it without to many problems.